# check for valid date issue

Tags: php

I would like to check for a valid date in 'mm/dd/yyyy' format. When I call the function below with `isValidDateTime('12/10/2012')`, it returns false. Could you please let me know what could be wrong?

```
function isValidDateTime($dateTime)
{
    if (preg_match("/^(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4}) ([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]):([01][0-9]|2[0-3])$/", $dateTime, $matches)) {
        if (checkdate($matches[1], $matches[3], $matches[2])) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" is *never* a good error description. Please describe what goes wrong, what error messages you get, etc.

Comment: if I called this function isValidDateTime('12/10/2012'), it returns false.

Comment: '12/10/2012' does not contain a time portion, which your regex is looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simpler way to accomplish your date validation ... it doesn't verify the mm/dd/yyyy format, but it doesn't need to.

The [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) constructor throws an exception if passed an invalid date string. Once you have a valid date, you can use [`DateTime::format()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) to output the date in any format you want.

```
$str = 'bad date';

try {
  $date = new DateTime($str);
  echo $date->format('m/d/Y');
  // do stuff
} catch(Exception $e) {
  echo "The date '$str' is not valid";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`isValidDateTime('12/10/2012')` will fail the `preg_match` condition, since you do not supply a time of the day.

Also, since you use `/` as a delimiter in your regular expression, you have to escape all other slashes, e.g., use `(\d{2})\/(\d{2})` instead of `(\d{2})/(\d{2})`.

Answer (score 0):

the string that will pass this check could look like this:
    01/02/2011 34/56/12

I don't think this is what you want to test, if you just want to test string "mm/dd/yyyy", use this:

```
/^(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})$/
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to escape the slashes (`/`-->`\/`)
2. The definition of `checkdate()` is: `$month, $day, $year` (swap the second and third parameter).

```
function isValidDateTime($dateTime)
{
    if (preg_match("/^(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4}) ([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]):([01][0-9]|2[0-3])$/", $dateTime, $matches)) {
        if (checkdate($matches[1], $matches[3], $matches[2])) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

var_dump( isValidDateTime('12/14/2011 00:00:00') ); // true
var_dump( isValidDateTime('12/14/s2011 00:00:00') ); // false
```